# Figuring out why the total number of outcomes is $n^k$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I have encountered two problems that are almost identical. Consider this: **$12$ basketballs numbered 1 through 12 are thrown at random into 20 boxes**. I want to know the total number of possible outcomes (assume order matters). The answer is $20^{12}$. In the other problem (which I do not need to mention), follows the same pattern and the answer is also $n^k$, where $n$ is the number of slots and $k$ is the number of objects I have. I came up with the $n^k$ conclusion by myself.

**I am just wondering, why is this the number of possible outcomes?**

Here are my efforts to understand it:

1. I Googled the problem, but I got no results.
2. I wanted to confirm that this $n^k$ conclusion is true. I did a simpler example of 2 objects and 4 slots and the result was matching the $n^k$ form.
3. I tried to use the multiplication principle (the counting one). We can say this: first stage throw all balls each basketball gets into a different box. It is `Perms(20, 12)`. Well, there is no a second stage. If I want to "add" more ways, I need to use the counting principle again in another context. Let us say make two balls in each box... etc. It is just a crazy overhead counting.
4. I tried to make an analogy with the problem of rolling two six-sided fair dice where the total outcomes of the pair they make is $6^6$. But it did not click with this basketball problem.

**Notes:**

1. **You can throw more than one basketball (at random) into one box.**
2. **This problem was encountered in a "probability stuff" context. I was able to go through the numerator but not this one.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you throw the first ball (the ball numbered 1). There are $n$ possible outcomes for this

Second, you throw the numbered 2 ball, there are also $n$ possible outcomes

and so on ...

Finally, you throw the last ball (the k-th ball), there are also $n$ possible outcomes

You use multiplication principle then you get the anwser is $n \times n \times ... \times n = n^k$ possible outcomes

Is that anwser your question?

Comment: I have not thought of it this way at all .. I mean the idea that each stage is basically throwing ONE ball at a time.

Answer (score 0):

What did you google?

The key word you need is combinatorix.  Specifically, combinatorix counting.  This site has a decent description of why.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Combinatorics

I hope it helps.

Comment: I googled the problem itself. I have not thought of googling n^k.